# Adding a new permission for google document content

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs-api, google-docs

I use google docs API(.net, c#) to share my document for other google user (ex: abc@gmail.com). Here's my code:

```
        AclEntry entry = new AclEntry();
        entry.Scope = new AclScope();
        entry.Scope.Type = AclScope.SCOPE_USER;
        entry.Scope.Value = "abc@gmail.com";

        entry.Role = new AclRole();
        entry.Role = AclRole.ACL_CALENDAR_READ;

        Service service = createService(szUserName, szPassword);
        string szAclUrl = ((DocumentEntry)contentEntry).AccessControlList;
        Uri AclUri = new Uri(szAclUrl);

        AtomEntry newAcl = service.Insert(AclUri, entry);
```

Note: service and contentEntry was created successfully.

But i get an error: `(400) Bad Request` when execute `service.Insert(AclUri, entry)` function.

What's i doing wrong? How can i add a new permission using google docs API(.net, c#)?

Answer (score 1):

I think edit

```
 entry.Role = new AclRole();
    entry.Role = AclRole.ACL_CALENDAR_READ;
```

to :

```
entry.Role = new AclRole("reader"); or entry.Role = new AclRole("writer");
```